# Do all special member functions need to be trivial for a class to be trivially copyable?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, trivially-copyable

The cppreference [page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) for the named requirement of being TriviallyCopyable, in the subsection for classes, lists the following requirement:

> **Trivially copyable class**
>
> A trivially copyable class is a class that
>
> - has at least one eligible copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator,
> - each eligible copy constructor is trivial
> - each eligible move constructor is trivial
> - each eligible copy assignment operator is trivial
> - each eligible move assignment operator is trivial, and
> - has a non-deleted trivial destructor.

so, if there's a trivial copy ctor but a non-trivial, say, move assignment operator - isn't the class trivially copyable? My intuition says that if you can construct an object of the same type by (trivially) memcpying the existing object (or assigning-by-memcpy to a constructed object) - that's trivial copyability.

Comment: I'm confused, the list of requirements specifically states "each eligible move assignment operator is trivial"

Comment: @Vivick: Well, can't I choose only one member to be elligible?

Comment: That would be true, but that would make the other move assignment operators dead code

Comment: @Vivick: But the requirement name is "Trivially**Copy**able".

Comment: If either of copy assignment or copy constructor is trivial but destructor is not, the rule 0/3/5 has most probably been violated. Any instance of any class must be destructed correctly to ensure resource-safety. If an object with none-trivial destructor is `memcpy`d, the destructor will entually commit **double-free** on underlying resources. Since triviality of copy is the precondition to using `memcpy`, it must consider triviality of destructor too.

Comment: @Red.Wave: Why would a destructor eventually commit "double free"? Or any free?

Comment: Because destructor is supposed to free the owned resource, and it is called once the object's lifetime ends. 2 instances leads to 2 destructor calls. If the 2 objects share same resource, it will be freed twice.

Comment: @Red.Wave: A destructor does not necessary free anything; that depends on the type.

Comment: @einpoklum You need to dig into RAII. If a type needs to define a destructor, it has some resource that must be freed in dtor. Why else would you need a destructor?

Comment: @Red.Wave: With respect - you're reversing the direction of implication: If a type needs to free some resource it holds, then it must define a destructor; but that's it.

Comment: @einpoklum there's no direction. A destructor that doesn't release any resource is excessive at best and harmful at worst. In either case everything in std definitions implies that compiler should assume none-trivial destructor releases resources, because it cannot prove otherwise, in general case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so, if there's a trivial copy ctor but a non-trivial, say, move assignment operator - isn't the class trivially copyable?

No, not if the copy constructor and move assignment operator are [eligible](https://eel.is/c++draft/special#def:special_member_function,eligible)<sup>☆</sup>, according to [the C++23 standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/n4950.pdf):

> ##### 11.2. Properties of classes [[class.prop]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.prop)
>
> 1. A *trivially copyable* class is a class:
>
>    1.1. — that has at least one eligible copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move
>    assignment operator ([[special]](https://eel.is/c++draft/special), [[class.copy.ctor]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor), [[class.copy.assign]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.assign)),
>
>    1.2. — where each eligible copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, and move assignment
>    operator is trivial, and
>
>    1.3. — that has a trivial, non-deleted destructor ([[class.dtor]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor)).
> 2. A *trivial class* is a class that is trivially copyable and has one or more eligible default constructors ([[class.default.ctor]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.default.ctor)),
>    all of which are trivial.
>
>    [*Note 1* : In particular, a trivially copyable or trivial class does not have virtual functions or virtual base classes.
>    — *end note*]

<sup>☆</sup>11.4.4. Special member functions

6. An *eligible* special member function is a special member function for which:

   6.1. the function is not deleted,

   6.2. the associated constraints, if any, are satisfied, and

   6.3. no special member function of the same kind is more constrained

Comment: But can't "elligible" be limited according to the context of use?

Comment: @einpoklum No. You can't choose when doing a `memcpy` for example.

Comment: I don't need to choose when doing a memcpy. A memcpy is copying, not moving. Plus, when doing a memcpy, I may be able to choose whether it's copy construction or copy assignment (depending on whether the target already has a constructed object).

Comment: @einpoklum I'm not sure I understand fully. Can you provide an example of a class with an eligible copy constructor and non-eligible move constructor (that is non-trivial) that you think should fall into the category of being trivially copyable?

Comment: @einpoklum [eligible](https://eel.is/c++draft/special#def:special_member_function,eligible) is defined independent of usage. Basically, a special member function is eligible if it can be called.

Comment: @JanSchultke Thanks for the edit. I added your link to the paragraph about eligible too. Cheers.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning the motivation for this definition. If a type is memcpy'd just because it has a trivial copy constructor, but then the move assignment operator does something like `this == expected_address`, something is seriously broken. The address would have changed by copying the bytes elsewhere, even though the address is important. Not a single eligible special member function can be "address-aware". It's an all-or-nothing thing.

Comment: @JanSchultke: The point regarding how "elligible" is defined is very important and I wish it would be made in one of the answers.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: An example: Make the copy ctor `= default` and have the move ctor mimic the default move ctor. Or have the move ctor also print something to `std::cout`.

Comment: @einpoklum I see what you mean. That would require some kind of inspection of the move ctor to recategorize it as trivial. I think one possible rationale for why the standard is what it is, is that it becomes "complicated". Not that complicated would be something new to C++, but still :-)

Answer (score 0):

The quote is correct. Each eligible copy/move operation must be trivial.

Trivial-copyability should mean that one is permitted to replace copying/moving of the object with `memcpy` without affecting semantics, and being allowed to use `memcpy` in this way is probably (originally) only for C compatibility as well. (Before C++11 split the POD concept, types were effectively required to be C types to be `memcpy`ied at all.)

But if some of the special member functions are not trivial, that's not generally guaranteed.

For example if only the copy assignment, but not the move assignment, is trivial, then

```
X x{};
Y y;
y = std::move(x);
```

should not be permitted to be replaced by

```
X x{};
X y;
std::memcpy(&y, &x, sizeof(X));
```

because that skips potential side effects that the move assignment should have.

So, `X` is specified not to be trivially-copyable.

And in any case the `memcpy` above has UB, because the permission to `memcpy` object representation between objects like this is specified in terms of trivial-copyability as well. As mentioned above, I think the reason for this is that the permission exists (at least originally) purely for C compatibility. Types that have non-trivial copy/move operations aren't relevant for C compatibility.

Even if the requirements on copying object representation with `memcpy` were weaker, so that only one of the copy/move operations needs to be trivial, then having the trivially-copyable concept require only one operation to be trivial would still not be useful, because any library function using it would still need to check triviality of individual operations instead in order to use it for optimization.

---

All of the above being said, there seems to have been some discussion in the standard committee on this, see https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1363.

Comment: But - in your example, the memcpy constructs a valid `X`, i.e. one has trivially copied `x` into `y`. The requirement isn't "TriviallyCopyableAssignableAndMoveable".

Comment: @einpoklum Because `X` isn't trivially-copyable it is not possible to copy object representation like that. Is your question really why https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#types.general-2 requires trivially-copyable rather than something weaker?

Comment: "Because X isn't trivially-copyable it is not possible to copy object represetnation like that."  <- You literally agreed that it is. That's the assumption you chose for X, that one can copy-construct from it by memcpying.

Comment: "Is your question really why eel.is/c++draft/basic#types.general-2 requires trivially-copyable" <- It's not what I asked, but it seems that question should only require trivial copy construction and copy assignment; or even: trivial copy-construction or move-construction, as well as trivial copy assignment or move assignment. 4 possible combinations of two trivial methods, not all 4 methods being trivial (and that's without getting into the question of destruction).

Comment: @einpoklum If your question is about what is or isn't permitted to be `memcpy`ied, rather than the usefulness of the type trait itself, then I think the answer is that this permission exists anyway only for C compatibility and so it considers only types that are effectively C types (before C++11 that was even stronger with the POD requirement).